# GeoDjango - Use GDAL python binding in the shell

Tags: python, gdal, geodjango

I would like to use the GDAL python binding in my GeoDjango site. The aim of this is to use ogr2ogr capabilities in a script. I am on windows 7 so I have installed GDAL-1.9.2.win32-py2.7 downloaded [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

The installation went correctly. I can import GDAL in python with: `from osgeo import GDAL`

However, in my geodjango app python shell, I have an error when I try to import osgeo. The error is the following:

```
>>> import osgeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in
t_helper_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: La procÚdure spÚcifiÚe est introuvable.
>>>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Im using GeoDjango v. 1.4.3 | python 2.7.3 | GDAL 1.9.2 win32

Comment: can you just use `import gdal`?

Comment: `import gdal` is depreciated in favor of `from osgeo import gdal`

Comment: I have the same error with import gdal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to head over to [gisinternals](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) and download GDAL.  Then you should have a working installation of GDAL from which `from osgeo import gdal` will work.

Comment: The link is dead.